# jQuery UI sortable with dynamic "connectWith" option

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm developing a page with 3 tables. On the 3rd table i have the rows that could be sorted and dropped on the 1st or 2nd table.

Is there a way I can define dynamically if a specific row can or can't be dropped on one of the other 2 tables? A sort of dynamized "connectWith" option...or any other way...

Answer (score 0):

You can define the rows of the third table using the `.draggable()` method of jQuery UI. 
Calling the draggable method, you can specify where the elements can be dropped.

Then on drag of the tr, hide the current tr from the current table (the third one).
On drop of the tr, get the table where you dropped the tr and add really the tr, really removing the row from the third table.
It's better that at the beginning you don't remove immediately the row from the third table, because if the drag event is not fine (for example I drop in a wrong place) you can show again the row.

Here a link to jQuery UI draggable method:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

A POC of code:

```
$( "#third-table tr" ).draggable({ 
    snap: ".drop-tables",
    start: function() {
        // hide the row from the third table
    },
    stop: function() {
        // add the row to the target table
        // remove the row from the third table
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You say "you can specify where the elements can be dropped". Am I missing something or the way you suggested is static as well as the way I'm already using with sortable's "connectWith" option? How can you dynamically telle the script where the row can be dropped?

Comment: Snap attribute specify the class of the droppable elements. Just use the same class to all the elements where you want to allow the drop

Comment: Ok, so you are suggesting to create N draggable instances? Is this really the only way? What if I have 50 tables? I really need something dynamic, on which i can execute a validation function and the return true or false to accept the drop or reject it...

Comment: Nope. So first, let's separate draggable from droppable.
I suggest you to use the same class for all the elements that will be draggable. 
And same class for the elements that will be accepted as drop area. 
This is dynamic and you can manage the elements to be draggable and droppable just using your CSS classes